# Wrapping my head around Object to World Coordinate transformations

Tags: graphics

So I am in a intro to Computer Graphics class and was struggling to convert object coordinates to world coordinates and so on. Would it just be a transform matrix to convert points from object->world? If anyone has any resources on this that would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The object to world transformation is fairly straightforward. When you open a modeler (say blender), you create an object, say a dog.

Let's assume the dog is posed such that its face point sin the -z direction, its paws are at height 0 and it's torso is centered along the xz plane (i.e half it;s body is on one side of the plane and the other half on the other).

That's model space, your dog is centered. However, you probably don;t want your dog there, your dog is somewhere different in world space. And he's likely in a different orientation as well.

Say we want our dog to be at location (36, 43, 0) with hi nose point in the direction (1,0,-1). This means that the dog needs to be moved to (36, 43, 0) which just means adding that vector to the models position. And we want to rotate him by 45 degrees, such that he looks in the desired direction.

The matrix transformation that encodes that rotation and translation is the model to world transformation.